# Validate data inside Data structure

Tags: oop, data-structures, dto

by definition: the data structure class, exposes its data (variables) and have no meaningful (significant) methods or functions.

My question would be what the `significant` word actually represents?

Currenly, I have a Data Structure that expose its data using getters and during these getters, I do the following

1. Validate the data
2. Transform it (ex. format Date time)

My question would be is that considered as `significant` work or data validation and transformation isn't really a behaviour method so my DS is still valid and not Hybrid class?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the difference between objects and data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406307/whats-the-difference-between-objects-and-data-structures)

Comment: I believe the word _meaningful_ indicates _business logic_; and validation is almost certainly business logic, so I'm afraid this sounds like a hybrid.

Comment: That's a really odd definition of a data structure. Where did you get it?

Comment: @JimMischel: _Clean Code_ by Robert Martin. See the potential dupe target that I linked for more information.

Comment: @jaco0646 What an odd definition. I wonder if the author even considered how confusing it would be to clash with the classical meaning of data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure

Comment: @jaco0646 by data validation, I mean like validate the value passed instance of DateTime Interface for example or that the value of this parameter > the value of the other parameter -> would you consider this as `business` logic? Thanks :)

Comment: I would probably move that logic somewhere else, yes. Consider: [parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/).