# Java use of is-A and has-A relationships

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

How come I can't use the variable shapeArea in my circle class? I'm trying to build a series classes with is-a relationships and has-a relationship for the first time. The empty classes don't really have a purpose yet. I was just trying to see if I could create the basic frame for what would eventually hold my code.

```
public class Object {
}

class shape extends Object{
}

class area{
    public double area;
}

class TwoDshape extends shape{
    area shapeArea = new area();
}

class circle extends TwoDshape{
    shapeArea.area = 1;
}
```

Comment: You can, but you have to do so in a method or a constructor or in a proper init block.

Comment: Define "can't use." You still need to use valid Java--there are language rules defining where/how you can use variable and arbitrary code.

Comment: Also, please forget the term "*is-a relationship*". It does more harm than good. A better concept for inheritance is the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Class names start with a capital letter. Please don't call multiple things `area`. Don't create your own class named `Object`. Your names make your code needlessly more difficult to reason about.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in any method in circle class or in any type of constructors of circle class because the inherited fields only can be accessed through constructors and methods in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

At the class level you can only define variables (static or instance), constructor, methods. You can do something like

```
class Circle extends TwoDshape{
    public Circle {
       shapeArea.area = 1;
    }
}
```

> Plus: Prefer starting class names with capital letter

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Replit snippet](https://replit.com/@huzz4/Inheritance-and-Hints).

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Shape2D shape = new Shape2D();
    System.out.println(shape.area.sqm);

    // Casting objects
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
    Shape2D circle = new Circle();
    System.out.println(circle.area.sqm);

    Shape2D triangle = new Triangle(2.0);
    System.out.println(triangle.area.sqm);


    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.increaseArea();
    System.out.println(rectangle.area.sqm);
  }
}


/*
  Extends java.lang.Object
  But if you omit that, it will extend implicitly.
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
*/
class Shape extends Object {

}


class Area {
  public double sqm;
}


class Shape2D extends Shape {
  Area area = new Area();
}


/*
  Initializing Instance Members
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html
*/
class Circle extends Shape2D {
  {
    area.sqm = 1.0;
  }
}


/*
  Using a constructor
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
*/
class Triangle extends Shape2D {
  Triangle(double areaInSquareMetres) {
    this.area.sqm = areaInSquareMetres;
  }
}


/*
  Using an instance method
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html
*/
class Rectangle extends Shape2D {
  void increaseArea() {
    area.sqm += 1.0;
  }
}
```

Also important:
[Whats the difference between objects and data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406307/whats-the-difference-between-objects-and-data-structures)